# using TFS API, is it possible to get who has last checkedin the file

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-2010

this is using TFS2010 API.

Given a file name, I need to get the details like folder path of the file, who checked in the last, datetime of last checkin.

Is there an API/WIQL that can help solve this?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, retrieving from a filename the SourceControl path(s) to this file, I couldn't find anything other than [this](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-enterprise-tools/860/How-do-I-find-a-file-in-TFS-Source-Control):

```
tf dir $/*file.cs /recursive /server:http://TFSServer:8080
```

Once you have the SourceControl path to the file, you can try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace ChangesetDetails
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFSServer:8080"));
            VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer) tpc.GetService(typeof (VersionControlServer));

            IEnumerable results = vcs.QueryHistory(@"$/../file.cs", 
                                                    VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, null, null, int.MaxValue, true, true);
            List<Changeset> changesets = results.Cast<Changeset>().ToList();
            Changeset latestChangeset = changesets.ElementAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This shall obtain the latest Changeset of `$/../file.cs`, which then can reveal the properties you 're after:

```
string lastCommiter = latestChangeset.Owner;
DateTime dateCommited =  latestChangeset.CreationDate;
```